# Git pull and merge and push specific changes without bringing in unrelated commits?

Tags: git

I have 1 develop branch and 1 project branch, the project branch has changes I want in develop but it also has changes I am not quite ready to put into develop. The project branch acts as the "develop" branch for myself while the develop branch is shared.

So my steps are:

1. Create a feature off the develop branch
2. git pull origin project.branch.name --no-commit (this will give me the diff and I can pick out the changes I want to add to develop before committing)
3. git push

This works fine except that it brings in commits that are not related to the changes I am pushing. The issue with bringing these commits in is that next time I want to do a pull request from the project to develop, it won't recognize the changes because develop will have the commits but not the code changes.

I looked into cherry picking but that's very tedious for changes that contain a lot of commits. Does anyone have an alternative solution?

Much appreciated!

**Update**
After extensive research, this is apparently not very common outside of working with monoliths. I have resolved the issue by gritting my teeth and cherry picking.

Comment: Could you illustrate your situation with a schema or a log and how you tried to cherry-pick? With ranges it's not that hard in many situations.

Comment: I agree, with ranges cherry picking isn't too bad but I'm assuming there is an alternative way because I feel that this is a common case that teams face.

Answer (score 1):

Step 2 gave me a headache. You are working *by hand* on changes that are coming from a branch? This is a problem for 2 main reasons:

- you are prone to (unwillingly, of course) add mistakes by editing files on the fly.
- even if you are flawless on the edition process before finishing the pull/merge operation, if you choose to get rid of changes related to a thing you don't want to have in your branch, those revisions *are* part of the history of the branch when you finish pulling/merging.

There are probably other problems with your approach but those are the biggest two I can think of.... and they are **big**.

Comment: It's only by hand in determining what files to commit but not hand on editing the code. I do agree there has to be a better approach. Is there an alternative approach you could recommend?